# Identifying the reason of the CPU pressure

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I see a high CPU pressure in the SQL Server and SQL Sentry shows only the following command which consumes the CPU abnormally. I think this is an internal process of the database engine but what stuff could be triggered this command?

**Note:** I am sure this is only a little part of the SQL statement which is used by the SQL Server

```
OPEN plan_handle_cursor;
```

Answer (score 4):

> I think this is an internal process of the database engine but what stuff could be triggered this command?

You could use monitoring tools (example Redgate SQL Monitor) where you can view, say, top 10 queries by CPU, reads etc. for a given period of time. Sort by CPU time, it will show top SQL statements that consumed most CPU. Expand any of these statements (example "OPEN plan_handle_cursor") , it will show a batch (or SP) to which your problematic statement belongs.

I am quite sure other monitoring tools (that are not free) can do the same.

You could also use free diagnostic tools, like:

1. sp_WhoIsActive - https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/releases
   Run it with "@get_plans = 2" parameter, to get execution plan. If you spot an "OPEN plan_handle_cursor" query in results in "sql_text" column, click on the "query_plan" column value, it will show an execution plan along with other statements in the batch
2. sp_PressureDetector - https://erikdarlingdata.com/sp_pressuredetector
3. sp_BlitzWho - https://downloads.brentozar.com/FirstResponderKit.zip

**Update**: for SQL Sentry, refer to this link: https://docs.sentryone.com/help/top-sql
It contains instructions on how to use Performance Analysis Top SQL. You should be able to get execution plan and full batch text to which "OPEN plan_handle_cursor" sql statement belongs

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have already tried before to post the question. SQL Sentry shows only this part of the query

Comment: @EsatErkec  tried  "sp_WhoIsActive", or "sp_PressureDetector", or "sp_BlitzWho", or Redgate, or what ?

Comment: I need more than them because it only occurred one time.